# how to implement QR code Scanner in WinJS

Tags: uwp, qr-code, winjs

I want to implement QR code  Scanner in WinJS for UWP apps. I have added reference of ZXing library but could not understand how to implement it in winJS project . I am using visual studio 2017.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the ZXing.Net on [github](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net#the-following-demo-clients-are-available), the demo client `Windows Store App with HTML5/JS (demonstrates decoding of static images)` is available but I have not found winJS demo. You could contact with them for requesting a winJS demo.

Comment: i implemented this demo in winJs but there one issue while scanning Qr code.Sometimes reader.decode(pixels, decoder.pixelWidth, decoder.pixelHeight,  ZXing.BitmapFormat.rgba32); this line return result but sometimes it return null even if there is QR code